# NoSuchElementException on Scanner, how do i get rid of it?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            if(s.next().contains(","))
            {
                String str= s.next().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
                List<String> brokenSentence = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
                writer.write(brokenSentence +"\n");
            }
            else
            {
                String edited = s.next().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");//error  
                writer.write(edited +"\n");
            }
        }
        s.close();
```

The line with error works perfectly without the if above,I really need that part. Please help me. The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at Programming_2021/free_time.Gutenburg2.main(Gutenburg2.java:67)
```

Comment: What is the Exact error that you get from this? Can you please provide the full message in the question via an [edit]?

Comment: Don't invoke `s.next()` twice.

Comment: how would I do it with just one instance of it? do I store it in a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't invoke `s.next()` twice, but assign the result of the first call to a variable:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String value = s.next();
        
    if(value.contains(",")) {
        String str = value.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        List<String> brokenSentence = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
        writer.write(brokenSentence +"\n");
    } else {
        String edited = value.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        writer.write(edited +"\n");
    }
}
```

Continuously calling `s.next()` will keep consuming values from the scanner. Those values are not necessarily there because you have only checked for the presence of one value using `s.hasNext()`.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! my issue now is when the if is provoked the answer is printed like this [words] because of the array, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: What do you want to print instead?

Comment: i want it to print; words, basically without braces

Comment: What if you have multiple elements?

Comment: all words must be on a new line, the split is there so the things with commas get split into new words on each line.

Comment: Then you have to loop over your list and print every entry on a new line. Or use `String.join()` with `\n` as a separator.

Comment: wow, that's very interesting. Just out of curiosity, can I use replaceAll(",", "/n");?

Comment: You'd have to call `toString()` on your list first, and would still be left with the square brackets.

Comment: List<String> brokenSentence = Arrays.asList(value.split("-"));
              String.join("/n", brokenSentence);
this did not work, what am i doing wrong?